# Creating ASP.Net Mobile Web Applications in VS 2010

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, mobile

I am trying to create a mobile version of a web application using VS2010 (.Net 3.5, not 4).  When I search for information on ASP.net mobile I see a lot of references to mobile controls that adapt their HTML to the specific device requesting the page.  Since I would like this app to be viewable on as many as devices as possible, it seems like it would be better to use the mobile controls rather than just create a smaller version of a web form.  Apparently VS2008 and up do not include the mobile control templates, but you can download and install them separately.  I did, but when I tried to create a test page I get a server error complaining that the assembly "System.Web.Mobile" could not be found.  I double checked in my references and that assembly is included in the project.  The file System.Web.Mobile.dll is also on the server running the app.

Is there something that I am doing wrong, or is developing a mobile web app in this way using VS2010 not possible?

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn´t found Mobile Web Forms templates for 2010 (for [2008](https://web.archive.org/web/20120714003706/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/webdevtools/archive/2007/09/17/tip-trick-asp-net-mobile-development-with-visual-studio-2008.aspx)). But Mobile Controls is a old and unused technology, you should use [MVC](https://web.archive.org/web/20101219010715/http://code.msdn.microsoft.com:80/WebAppToolkitMobile).